# Python context-managed member variable?

Tags: python

Context managers define setup/cleanup functions `__enter__` and `__exit__`. Awesome. I want to keep one around as a member variable. When my class object goes out of scope, I want this cleanup performed. This is basically the behavior that I understand happens automatically with C++ constructors/destructors.

```
class Animal(object):

    def __init__(self): 
        self.datafile = open("file.txt") # This has a cleanup function
        # I wish I could say something like...
        with open("file.txt") as self.datafile: # uh...

    def makeSound(self):
        sound = self.datafile # I'll be using it later

# Usage...
if True:
    animal = Animal()
# file should be cleaned up and closed at this point.
```

Answer (score 5):

Python doesn't do C++-style RAII ("Resource Acquisition Is Initialization", meaning anything you acquire in the constructor, you release in the destructor). In fact, almost *no* languages besides C++ do C++-style RAII. Python's context managers and `with` statements are a *different* way to achieve the same thing that C++ does with RAII, and that most other languages do with `finally` statements, `guard` statements, etc. (Python also has `finally`, of course.)

---

What exactly do you mean by "When my class object goes out of scope"?

Objects don't go out of scope; references (or variables, or names, whatever you prefer) do. Some time after the last reference goes out of scope (for CPython, this is immediately, unless it's involved in a reference cycle; for other implementations, it's usually not), the object will be garbage-collected.

---

If you want to do some cleanup when your objects are garbage-collected, you use the `__del__` method for that. But that's rarely what you actually want. (In fact, some classes have a `__del__` method just to warn users that they forgot to clean up, rather than to silently clean up.)

---

A better solution is to make `Animal` *itself* a context manager, so it can manage other context managers—or just manage things explicitly. Then you can write:

```
if True:
    with Animal() as animal:
        # do stuff
    # now the file is closed
```

Here's an example:

```
class Animal(object):

    def __init__(self): 
        self.datafile = open("file.txt")

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        self.datafile.close()

    def makeSound(self):
        sound = self.datafile # I'll be using it later
```

(Just falling off the end of `__exit__` like that means that, after calling `self.datafile.close()`, we successfully do nothing if there was no exception, or re-raise the same exception if there was one. So, you don't have to write anything explicit to make that happen.)

---

But usually, if you're going to make a class into a context manager, you also want to add an explicit `close`. Just like files do. And once you do that, you really don't need to make `Animal` into a context manager; you can just use [`closing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.closing).

Answer (score 5):

I  give classes a `close` function if it makes sense and then use the [`closing`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.closing) context manager:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.resource = acquire_resource()

    def close():
        release_resource(self.resource)
```

And then use it like:

```
from contextlib import closing

with closing(MyClass()) as my_object:
    # use my_object
```