# Is it possible to transfer ownership of a context manager?

Tags: python, contextmanager

In the RAII world of C++, it's not uncommon to transfer ownership of resources from one resource-managing object to another (such as via copying or moving).  Is there any equivalent with Python context managers?

That is, if I wrote a function:

```
def open_and_do_something(filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        do_something_that_might_raise(f)
```

Is there any way for `open_and_do_something` to return `f` to the caller or cancel the context manager?  Must such a function be written using `try` .. `except`?

In C++, I typically could cancel management by doing something like:

```
FILE* open_and_do_something(const std::string& filename)
{
    MyFileWrapper f(fopen(filename.c_str(), "r"));
    do_something_that_might_raise(f)

    // We made it here alive.
    return f.release();
}

// And in the calling code...
MyFileWrapper f(open_and_do_something(filename));
```

In Python, I've tried doing:

```
def open_and_do_something(filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        do_something_that_might_raise(f)
        # We made it here alive.
        ret = f
        f = dummy_context_manager()
        return ret
```

but it appears that reassigning `f` does not change what the `with` block calls `__exit__` on.

Comment: What do you mean *"return `f` to the caller?"* The thing that calls `open_and_do_something`? If yes, then you'd have to write your own context manager so the caller could use `with open_and_do_something(...) as f:`

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes.  I was hoping for something less work/less awkward than having to make my own context manager.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Hm, while the answers at [Python context-managed member variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27072664/python-context-managed-member-variable) are relevant, the question is completely different.

Comment: Closing dupes is more about the answers than the questions - if the answers there don't fully answer your question, please [edit] to clarify what else you need to know.

Comment: @jonrsharpe It kind of depends what they want to do with `f`.  `f` will still exist as a "file" (`IOWrapper`, or what have you), it just won't be open anymore.  You could `return f` from that function and access, say, the `f.name` attribute without issue.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Since my question is completely different from that one, there's no way for me to know that the answers there are the best-suited answers to *my* question. (I guess I object to the "This question was marked as an *exact* duplicate..." phrasing.) Now that I've done some more searching, I think [How to return from with statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36857600/how-to-return-from-with-statement) is really more appropriate.

Comment: @jamesdlin that's the same answer, making the function itself into a context manager. *"there's no way for me to know..."* - that makes no sense to me, surely you can apply them to your problem and see what happens? Your question *isn't* completely different, you want to keep a context-managed object around after the end of the `with` block.

Comment: Guys, a context managed object *does* stay around after a `with` block.  All the end of a `with` block does is "close" it (or whatever the `__exit__` method says).  It doesn't disappear.  It can still be passed around like anything else, returned from functions, copied, reopened later, etc.

Comment: @jedwards yes, you're right; the object is still there but the *context* is over, after which the object isn't necessarily very useful!

Comment: @jonrsharpe This, I can agree with.

Comment: *"it appears that reassigning `f` does not change what the `with` block calls `__exit__` on"* - why would it? `f` is just *your* name for it, `__exit__` will be called on `self` which is still the original object.